# Registration form in php using oop

Tags: php, sql

I just want to make a registration page but I'm stuck in this error -

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   C:\wamp\www\2209login\register.php on line 25*

and this one ->

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::create() in
>   C:\wamp\www\2209login\register.php on line 30

**database.php**

```
<?php
// used to get mysql database connection
class Database{

    // specify your own database credentials
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "ooplogin";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    // get the database connection
    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            echo "connected";
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

**user.php**

```
<?php
// 'user' object
class User{
  // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "users";

     // object properties
    public $id;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $email;

      // constructor
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
        // create new user record
function create(){
 $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                firstname = :firstname,
                lastname = :lastname,
                email = :email";

                   // prepare the query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

     // sanitize
    $this->firstname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->firstname));
    $this->lastname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->lastname));
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));

    // bind the values
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $this->firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $this->lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email);

    // execute the query, also check if query was successful
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        $this->showError($stmt);
        return false;
    }
}
}
}
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
// core configuration
//include_once "config/core.php";

// set page title
$page_title = "Register";

// include login checker
//include_once "login_checker.php";

// include classes
include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/user.php';
//include_once "libs/php/utils.php";

// include page header HTML
//include_once "layout_head.php";

if($_POST){

    // get database connection
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $user->firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $user->lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $user->email=$_POST['email'];

    // create the user
if($user->create()){

    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
        echo "Successfully registered. <a href='{$home_url}login'>Please login</a>.";
    echo "</div>";
    }else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Unable to register. Please try again.</div>";
}
}
?>
<form action='register.php' method='post' id='register'>

    <table class='table table-responsive'>

        <tr>
            <td class='width-30-percent'>Firstname</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='firstname' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['firstname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Lastname</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='lastname' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['lastname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
 <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <td></td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Register
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Neither data are inserting in database.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$user = new User()` is missing on your register.php

Comment: thanks Mr. Masivuye first error has solved but still second error ->Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::create()

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: no I just use notepade++,if any one good please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate  `__construct` and `create` method. In your current code create method is inside constructor, change your user class to:

```
// 'user' object
class User{
  // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "users";

     // object properties
    public $id;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $email;

      // constructor
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;

    }
        // create new user record
     public function create(){
         $query = "INSERT INTO
                        " . $this->table_name . "
                    SET
                        firstname = :firstname,
                        lastname = :lastname,
                        email = :email";

                           // prepare the query
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

             // sanitize
            $this->firstname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->firstname));
            $this->lastname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->lastname));
            $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));

            // bind the values
            $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $this->firstname);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $this->lastname);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email);

            // execute the query, also check if query was successful
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return true;
            }else{
                $this->showError($stmt);
                return false;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
include 'db5.php';
//user data insertion in database
class B
{

    public function register()
    {

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_POST['username']); 
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_POST['email']); 
$password    = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_POST['password']); 
$repassword  = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_POST['repassword']); 

$password = md5($password);


    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO opps(username, email, password, repassword) values('$username', '$email', '$password', '$repassword')";
    $result = mysqli_query($obj->conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($sql2));
    echo "Registration Successfull!";

   print_r($sql2);
//}
//else
//{
    //echo "Registration Failed.";
//}
}
}


public function login()

{

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
$emailusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_POST['email']); 
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_POST['password']); 
$password = md5($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM opps WHERE email = '$emailusername' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($obj->conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//$active=$row['active'];
//$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($row['username']==$emailusername && $row['password']==$password) 
       {

         echo "login successfully" .$row['username'];

       } 
       else
       {
        echo "login failed";
       }


}

}

$obj2 = new B();
$obj2->register();
$obj2->login();


?>
```

Comment: Please, explain why & how your code works so that the answer and question can be valuable to less experiences developers